# Page zoom in bigger screen

Tags: screen-resolution, distortion, page-layout, zooming

This image is of my website.It opens very beautifuly in medium and small screens(less than `1024x768` resolution).But when I open it in bigger browser it dosen't look like what it was.I mean it becomes quite `small` compared to the `screen size`.Question is ,Is there a option to make it look good on bigger screens.and if there is a way-> **Than tell me.**. :)

My site's Address: [www.Xeemez.com](http://www.xeemez.blogspot.com)

**NOTE**: When I `zoom-in or zoom-out` on bigger screens than the **MENU** below the header section becomes distorted so keeping that in mind please suggest some solution.By the way this `zoom-in and zoom-out distortion problem` also happens in smaller screen.Thank You.

[image]

Comment: Your problem is not a new one: check out [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/#a2) from smashing magazine.

Comment: As simple as that I want my main menu to be in same line while zooming-in. Nothing related to responsive pages as such.or may be a little bit.

Comment: To me, your main menu is not on the same line at any zoom level. The best way to do this though, is to somehow manually set the widths of each child so that they add up to the total width. Then, to fix the zoom-level issues, you can just add `margin-right: -1px` to the parent `<ul>`.

Comment: I am using your site on a Retina Mac and it works fine.